# Why is the dd comand failing to open and/or unable to find my raspian.img file?

Tags: sd-card, dd, raspberrypi

Noob here, first post. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 amd64. I want to flash raspian onto an 8GB microsd card. I have been unsuccessful.

The command I entered is:

```
sudo dd if=2015-09-24-raspian-jessie.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M
```

The error message is:

```
dd: failed to open ‘2015-09-24-raspian-jessie.img’: No such file or directory
```

I then try being more specific in the path to the file:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/2015-09-24-raspian-jessie.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=5M
```

But get the same result:

```
dd: failed to open ‘/home/handsome/Downloads/2015-09-24-raspian-jessie.img’: No such file or directory
```

So then I double check to see if the file is there and it is:

```
cd Downloads
Downloads$ ls
2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.img    2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.img
```

What gives?

Comment: There is a spelling mistake in your file name.

Comment: @Jay Not sure it is a spelling mistake: may be he re-named the file either by intention or mistake

Answer (score 4):

You are consistently mistyping the name, which has a "b" in it.

Answer (score 1):

First, run `ls -l` to be sure your file is there. Then specify the full path to that file must be given instead:

> sudo dd if=/home/your_session_name/Downloads/2015-09-24-raspian-jessie.img
>   of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M

This should remove away that error message you get.